# Programmatically Adding a Barcode to a Page in ActiveReports

Tags: vb.net, activereports

I have code which is implementing an interface giving me access to a DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.Document. From there I'm able to access the different Pages in the document. I've also created a DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Barcode.

I can't seem to find a way to add the barcode onto a Document or if it's possible at all.

I have some sample code which manages to do it by creating a brand new active report, adding the barcode, then exporting it as an image, croping the image, and drawing the image to the page, but I was hoping there was a more direct way.

Comment: Can you change the font of objects on the reports? If so, change one to a barcode font. Don't forget to add * to the start and end of the text, so it's scannable.

Comment: I can change the fonts, and I've seen one way is to change to a barcode font and then use drawtext. I would need to install additional fonts for barcodes and QR codes though from what I can tell.

Comment: Well that's the only way I know how to do barcodes unless you paste images (which I wouldn't recommend). You need a barcode font. Change some field's font to the barcode font and voila, you will see barcodes there. To be scannable, it's much more tedious: * at the start and end of the text value, certain barcode font size, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once a report document is generated, it is a static snapshot of the report AFTER it was run.  You cannot add control to that document anymore; you can still do document manipulation using the document/page api.  for example, you can add/remove pages, draw text, borders on the pages and etcs..

take a look at the page api here:
http://tinyurl.com/nxv7wct

If you want to add a barcode control to the report; you have to add it to to the report layout and then run the report again.  it will then be available in the report document.